# SwiftUI: Fetching a shuffled array from Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to fetch a **shuffled** array from Core Data into a view. I suppose I am missing some simple solution, because so far it's proving to be surprisingly difficult.

1. This draws an empty view:

```
struct ChildView: View {
    var entityData: FetchRequest<Entity>
    var shuffledEntities: [Entity]
    
    init() {
        entityData = FetchRequest<Entity>(entity: Entity.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Entity.name, ascending: true)])

        shuffledEntities = entityData.wrappedValue.shuffled()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(shuffledEntities) { entity in
                Text(entity.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. The only solution I have is by fetching the Entity in a parent view and pre-shuffling it before this view is loaded, like this:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest<Entity>(entity: Entity.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Entity.name, ascending: true)])
    var entityData: FetchedResults<Entity>
    @State var shuffledEntities: [Entity] = []

    var body: some View {

        if shuffledEntities.isEmpty {
           Color.clear
            .task{
               shuffledEntities = entityData.shuffled()
            }
        } else {
            ChildView(shuffledEntities: shuffledEntities)
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not ideal, because there are times when I need the Child View to redraw itself, and for data to be re-fetched.

3. I also found a working solution wherein I moved the if-statement to the Child view, like this:

```
struct ChildView: View {
    var entityData: FetchRequest<Entity>
    @State var shuffledEntities: [Entity] = []
    
    init() {
        entityData = FetchRequest<Entity>(entity: Entity.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Entity.name, ascending: true)])
    }
    
    var body: some View {

        if shuffledEntities.isEmpty {
           Color.clear
            .task{
               shuffledEntities = entityData.shuffled()
            }
        } else {
            VStack {
                ForEach(shuffledEntities) { entity in
                    Text(entity.name)
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

But this breaks the animation when the Child view is initially drawn. It just immediately pops onto the screen.

At this point I'm not sure where to turn, so any recommendations are much welcome, thank you in advance!

Comment: Unrelated but as Core Data saves its records unordered you get a *shuffled* array by default if no sort descriptor is specified.

Comment: true but the order will be the same every time the view is drawn, right? I want a different order every time the view is redrawn